# Entrada de valores na matriz

Tags: java, array

Tenho o seguinte código que lê uma matriz 10x10:

```
public class t151 {

    static final int n = 10;

    public static void main (String[] args){

        int A[][] = new int [n][n];

        int i,j;

        for (i=0; i < n; i++){
            for (j=0; j < n; j++){
                System.out.print (A[i][j]); 
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Como faço para inserir manualmente os 100 elementos dessa matriz?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que pretendes fazer? Pelo menos para mim não ficou muito claro.

Comment: Na verdade um array de inteiros(primitivo) é iniciado com todas as posições em 0. E na outra pergunta você disse que queria saber a causa do erro `ArrayIndexOfBoundException`apenas. Para trabalhar com cada posição da matriz, basta alterar a linha do `System.out.println` com o que quer que cada posição receba. Dá uma editada no texto, explicando melhor o que quer fazer assim facilita elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: pelo o que eu entendi o código só está gerando as posições da matriz, tanto que sua saída pelo meno aqui está sendo:
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000‌​00000000000000000000‌​00000000000000000000
Gostaria de saber como eu colocaria manualmente os valores de cada posição (de cada elemento) como entrade do usuário (digitando cada elemento) ou como eu ajustaria no código uma sequencia aleatoria, por exemplo, que medesse uma saída assim: 1234567 etc.

Comment: eu consigo fazer isso para vetores mas não consigo para matriz

Comment: Veja meu comentario anterior(se não aparecer completo, atualize esta pagina).

Comment: editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a intenção é preencher manualmente a matriz, como disse nos comentários, basta alterar a linha dentro do for mais interno, fazendo a matriz receber o dado desejado. O *for* mais externo controla a mudança das linhas da matriz, e o *for* interno controla a mudança de colunas em cada linha.

No código abaixo, seria necessário entrar com as 100 posições via entrada de usuario:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class t151 {

    static final int n = 10;

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int A[][] = new int [n][n];

        int i,j;

        //este laço controla a mudança de linhas da matriz
        for (i=0; i < n; i++){
            //já este laço controla
            // a mudança de colunas em cada linha da matriz
            for (j=0; j < n; j++){
                A[i][j] = sc.nextInt(); 
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Se for pra preencher com algum outro valor, que não venha de uma entrada de usuario, basta remover o `sc.nextInt()` e colocar o dado que será armazenado.

Veja o exemplo funcionando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/TVosuZ).

Comment: como nos vetores a entrada fica dentro do laço daúnica linha a minha duvida era de como se faria na matriz, se seria em duas partes (primeiro dentro do laço das linhas e depois das colunas). essa era a dúvida

Comment: @Leko editei a resposta explicando melhor como funciona este tipo de laço, veja se dá pra entender com clareza, qualquer coisa, só comentar :)

Comment: muitíssimo obrigado

Comment: @Leko você sabe que pode votar em tudo no site? Pode votar em todas respostas dadas em perguntas suas (não só a que você aceitou, pode votar em outras perguntas, em respostas de outras coisas que não sejam suas que você achar legal. Seria bom dar uma revisada pelo menos nas suas perguntas e ver se as respostas dadas nelas merecem um voto. Se não sabe a diferença entre aceitar uma resposta e votar, veja o [tour].