# erro ao preencher matriz usando valores do input em java

Tags: java, lógica

Estou com um desafio da faculdade que envolve fazer o produto de matriz. porem quando eu tento inserir os números e passar eles para a matriz ocorre o seguinte erro: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 0;
na linha mat[x][y] = scan.nextInt();

public class desafio {
public static void main (String[] args){

```
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int[][] mat=new int[x][y];
    int z = 0;
    int u = 0;
    int[][] mat2=new int[z][u];
    int soma;

    System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de linhas: ");
    x = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de colunas: ");
    y = scan.nextInt();
    
    //soma = x * y;
    
    for (i=0;0<x;i++){
        for (j=0;0<y;j++){
            System.out.println("Digite um valor: ");
            mat[x][y] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }

    for (int i=0;0<x;i++){
        for (int j=0;0<y;j++){
            System.out.printf("matriz: ",mat[i][j]);
            
        }
    }

    
}
```

}`

Comment: coloca o código na pergunta, mano.

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Entrada de valores na matriz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163244/entrada-de-valores-na-matriz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para entender melhor como preencher um array bidimensional, podemos fazer um paralelo a preencher uma tabela(apesar da informação não ser guardada dessa forma na memória).

Quando você tem um array de duas dimensões como `mat[3][4]`, precisa de dois laços interagindo entre si para preencher todas as dimensões. Enquanto o primeiro laço vai manter-se fixo numa dimensão(como se fosse a linha da tabela), o outro irá varrendo a outra dimensão(como se fosse colunas da tabela).

Porém, no teu código tem outro problema. Você declara as variáveis que deveriam representar o tamanho das dimensões como 0, e depois altera os valores dela. Como seus arrays já foram instanciados com o tamanho 0, seus laços sempre irão estourar `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` quando `y` e `x` forem alterados para valores maiores que 0. A solução para isso é deixar para instanciar os arrays apenas depois que o usuário decidiu o tamanho.

A lógica seria assim:

```
int linha = 0;
int coluna = 0;
//você somente declara a variável, mas nao instancia
int[][] array2D;

//aqui você pode perguntar ao usuário os tamanhos

//uma vez validados, você pode instanciar o array
array2D = new int[linha][coluna];


//o primeiro laço manterá o fluxo da primeira dimensão
//já o laço mais interno percorrerá os elementos cruzando as duas dimensões

    for(i = 0; i < linha; i++)
    {
        for(j =0; j < coluna; j++)
        {
             array2D[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Veja funcionando corretamente no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/wTnUvB)

Deve-se atentar também a não permitir que os valores de dimensões não sejam negativos pra não ocorrer erro ao instanciar o array.

Há formas mais otimizadas e reduzidas de se fazer isso, mas como o objetivo é didático, creio que esta solução atenda.

Comment: Acabei por ver que a pergunta era duplicata, então, sinalizei a mesma, há necessidade de remover a resposta?

Comment: eu fiz as mudanças que você falou e ainda sim ele me da o mesmo erro, e olhei a outra pergunta similar a minha e é quase idêntico ao oque eu quero fazer e mesmo assim não funciona

Comment: sim, porem a galera do techpeopleBR(servidor do discord) achou o erro, erra na  condição do for(int j=0;0<y;j++) o certo é for (int j=0;i < x && j < y;j++)

Comment: @RafaelAcílio perdão, havia um errinho de digitação no código da resposta, agora está corrigido e funcionando, você pode ver em funcionamento no link que adicionei.

Comment: Na verdade  erro estava na linha `array2D[linha][coluna] = scan.nextInt();` dentro do segundo laço, era só trocar pelos indices `i` e `j`

Comment: eu percebi isso e fiz a troca ai nao funcionou mas depois que eu arrumei a condição como me sugeriram funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Você chegou a ver o link q mandei? nele esta o código inteiro funcionando, conforme alterei.

Comment: sim eu vi e não consigo entender porque nao quer funcionar aqui no meu, não sei se é alguma coisa do vscode ou oque que pode ser

Comment: continua dando indexofbound?

Comment: mas obrigado pela sua ajuda, ja salvou de mais

Comment: sim ele continua dando indexofbound

Comment: olha a linha que ocorre o erro, como vc ta trabalhando com vários arrays no seu codigo, pode ser q o erro esteja ocorrendo em outro pedaço que você ainda nao alterou

Comment: Essa resposta está mais completa, se quiser depois tentar ajustar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/415836/164151